# Is there a general format for LaTeX commands?

Tags: macros, environments, syntax

I am quite new to LaTeX and as I was reading the LaTeX Wikibook I came upon the following general definition for a command in LaTeX [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Basics#LaTeX_commands):

```
\commandname[option1,option2,...]{argument1}{argument2}...
```

However, [later on](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros#New_commands) in the Wikibook the syntax for creating a new command is given as:

```
\newcommand{name}[num][default]{definition}
```

Now given the general definition for a command in LaTeX I would have instead expected the following syntax for creating a new command:

```
 \newcommand[num,default]{name}{definition}
```

A bit later on in the same section on creating macros in the LaTeX wikibook the syntax for creating a new environment [is given as](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros#New_environments):

```
\newenvironment{name}[num][default]{before}{after}
```

Again, given the general definition I would have expected this instead:

```
 \newenvironment[num,default]{name}{before}{after}
```

I would appreciate it greatly if somebody could clarify this inconsistency for me.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  The nice thing about TeX is that it has almost no syntax of itself. The syntax is defined by _you_ (or in this case, by LaTeX). Commands defined with `\newcommand` will invariably have the syntax `\cmd{<arg1>}{<arg2>}...` or `\cmd[<opt>]{<arg1>}{<arg2>}...`. Commands defined with `xparse` have much more flexibility, and you can also define the commands  by hand to have virtually _any_ syntax you want.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I don't find the LaTeX Wikibook a very reliable guide. Some commands accept comma separated options, but the vast majority doesn't. And a command can have multiple optional arguments, one case is indeed [math]\newcommand[/math].

Comment: The only somewhat consistent convention is to use `[]` for optional arguments and `{}` for mandatory ones. Third type is `()` for coordinates, but those are pretty rare in the LaTeX format itself (`picture`-mode). There are some classes and packages however that break this general rule and add optional braced arguments, so not even those are safe. And the concept of `key=value` optional arguments is relatively young, so the older the macro the less likely they are used.

Comment: Also, while it is possible in theory to use optional arguments in fully expandable macros, a `key=value` syntax will most likely never be fully expandable, so there might be macros which take normal and possibly multiple optional arguments in the distant future, when `key=value` has otherwise fully took over.

Comment: Could you explain what `key=value` means?

Comment: It should be noted that `\commandname` is not a standard macro, but rather an example of how to use a macro, while `\newcommand` is a LaTeX macro used to create new commands (replacing the original TeX `\def\name#1#2...{definition}`).

Comment: @TheRiddler suppose I want to make a command to include images in a document. I probably want to scale them several different optional ways, e.g. specify a scale factor, or the required width or height, or rotate the image through an angle, or whatever. The easiest way to do that in TeX or LaTeX is make a command with *one* (optional) argument that might look like `width=2in,rotate=90` etc rather than having several arguments, or several different commands for different options.

Comment: Another unusual syntax are in the `lipsum` commads  (e.g. `\lipsum[1][1-3]`) where are not allowed any arguments. And you an also face with constructs like `\cmidrule{1-3}(rl)`   with the `booktabs` package, where the part in () is optional too.  To clarify the question (or may be help to the confusion) think about this code:  `\def\bold*#1*{{\bfseries #1}} \def\italics<#1>{\textit{#1}}` this allow you to use  `\bold*foo*` or `\italics<baz>`. It is hard maintain a consistent syntax in hundreds of packages when you can make almost anything.